# How to secure REST APIs and not JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am trying to have unsecured DAOs and secured REST APIs using Spring Data, Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Rest.

For example, I have the **DAO repository** which **should not be secured** since I want to call its methods from anywhere without having to provide an authentication:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false, path = "persons")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    int countByUsername(String username);

    void deleteByUsername(String username);

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

And I have the **REST repository**, which **must be secured** using authorizations of the current user:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "persons")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('FETCH_USER')")
public interface UserRestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('DELETE_USER')")
    @Override
    void delete(User user);

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('DELETE_USER')")
    @Override
    void deleteAll();

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('DELETE_USER')")
    @Override
    void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends User> iterable);

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('DELETE_USER')")
    @Override
    void deleteById(Long id);

    @Override
    Iterable<User> findAll();

    @Override
    Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Override
    Iterable<User> findAll(Sort sort);

    @Override
    Iterable<User> findAllById(Iterable<Long> iterable);

    @Override
    Optional<User> findById(Long id);

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SAVE_USER')")
    @Override
    <S extends User> S save(S s);

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SAVE_USER')")
    @Override
    <S extends User> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> iterable);
}
```

The problem here is that it seems to automatically use the JpaRepository to create and configure the REST service, so I am forced to add `exported = false` on it to only expose methods of the REST repository, BUT there's still a problem, if I want to set change path (to persons) on the REST service, it doesn't work, I still need to duplicate it on the JpaRepository...

Am I not supposed to do like this ?
Is it not possible to create a separate JpaRepository and PagingAndSortingRepository, one for the DAO and the other for the REST ?

Comment: I used RepositoryRest for years and have good conceptioal and bad perfomancial experiences with it. The performance leads me to not use RepositoryRest anymore and I had to undo the introduction of RepositoryRest.

Comment: Secure the endpoints (URLs) using Spring Security rather than the methods. https://www.javabullets.com/spring-security-spring-data-rest/

Comment: @AlanHay I finally ended up with your solution, it fits my needs, would you mind creating an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Secure the endpoints (URLs) using Spring Security rather than the
>   methods. javabullets.com/spring-security-spring-data-rest

See Alan Hays comment